# Unwanted transparent SupportMapFragment over OpenGL surface view on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es

I am trying to use the Google Maps API V2 for Android using the SupportMapFragment and I have a problem when I add the map on top of a surface view that uses opengl and camera.

The thing is that I add the fragment dinamically on top of the surfaceview and all I get is the zoom controls but a transparent map.

Is there any incompatibily with applications that are already using opengl?

Should I destroy the opengl context before loading the map?

Can it be other problem like wrong API key, permission, etc?

Is there anything I can do to make it work with other opengl surface?

**UPDATE**: I managed to show the map on an independent activity (ProgramaticDemoActivity.java) so it is not an API KEY problem (although I had to create a new API console project).

Then I tried again over my surface view and I can see the map but not always. I usually get null when calling mMapFragment.getMap(). Even after I add the fragment to the layout (programmatically) so maybe the onCreateView is not called fast enough. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Since Map API V2, it uses GL surface. Older API might respect some z-ordering as it uses simple 2D canvas to draw maps.

As of now android isn't capable of handling overlapping EGL surfaces in specific order. 
Being special kind of views that punch through the rest in some sense to directly access that rectangular frame of memory, these won't respect z-order mentioned in your layout.

On different run even on the same device, its more or less a coin toss as to which one comes on top.

See Dianne's reply in: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/COffLpanlz0

But do explore [setZOrderMediaOverlay()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html#setZOrderMediaOverlay%28boolean%29) and setZOrderOnTop() for your GL Surface. You might have some luck.

Workarounds:

- could try Map API V1 which might see its plug pulled by the time your app gets famous
- could instead use web API for static map bitmap that has stringent free quota (pay for more)

Or feel free to star [issues (eg. #6613)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=6613) and wait.

Comment: the surface created by the google maps library doesn't allow to set the z order, how could I set my surface behind?

Comment: this is what I figured was happening, thanks for explaining and those links!

Comment: @ferdy182, consider splitting the screen (eg. LinearLayout of the two) instead of trying to overlap. Overlap of GL surfaces is probably not going to work consistently.

Comment: @hoperon I need them to be fullscreen so the only way would be overlapping them or removing the bottom one to add the map surface, but in that case, I would lost all the contents of the opengl surface view

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "transparent map"? You see the map tiles "transparent" or you see nothing at all (only zoom controls and no tiles)?

Have you tried to use the SupportMapFragment without the OpenGL layers? Just to discard API key problems.

I had the same problem I used Google Maps Activities, and I solved it testing and testing again, but I think the problem was related to the Maps API Key.

Comment: I have a camera preview behind the map fragment and I can see it through it. I know it is there because I can see the zoom controls but no map at all.

Is not the API key because I managed to show it (I created a new API project in the console) but when I call the mMapFragment.getMap() it is null, not always, even if I add the fragment first, looks like the onCreateView is not yet called.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot getMap() directly after adding the MapFragment...you must wait until it is ready. Suggest you create a MyCustomisedMapFragment and have it do something in its onResume method to tell your other code its ready for you to getMap().

Comment: I managed to show the map but my problem is that I cannot change between the map and the surface view by adding/removing or showing/hiding the fargment.

Comment: showing the map is solved, the problem is that is transparent when set above a surfaceview that uses opengl

Comment: I had asked about that exact posibility in the Android Developers Office Hours in december that showcased the new maps API v2. Answer was: no. Also because its seemingly (and said to be, again in that Office Hours) not possible to access the FrameBuffer for GoogleMap you can't do any trickery such as scraping the buffer to display elsewhere :( If you find a way forward with any of those problems, please do let us all know!

Comment: BTW what I said above touches on something that might help you to get the overlaid surfaceView's content actually overlaying: scrape it's FrameBuffer and add as bitmap (ImageView) ontop of the GoogleMap view. Won't perform very well but it's perhaps a means to an end.